# Chrome won't start - Windows 7 x64 is complaining about compatibility

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, compatibility, 64-bit

Suddenly Chrome browser does not start, my Windows 7 x64 is complaining:

[image: Error message screen]

In translation:

> The version of this file is not
>   compatible with the version of Windows
>   you’re running. Check your computer’s
>   system information to see whether you
>   need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit)
>   version of the program, and then
>   contact the software publisher.

Reinstalling did not help. The things that changed and I have noticed are system updates and Java update.

Any ideas, what to do to resolve the issue or troubleshoot it?

Comment: Does the error message give a file name?

Comment: I does: c:\Users\WooYek\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall, restart, and reinstall through google pack did the trick, unfortunately all my settings are gone :(